# Display a set of divs left to right without breaking their rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to echo a set of divs left to right with no overlapping their rows... It's something like this.

[image]

As you can see, the horizontal row is not broken. Each line starts after the longest (in height) div ends.

I'm looping through an array and each square represent one element. The height may be coming as a data in the array.

So, what's the way of doing this ?

Update:

Here's what I have tried...

```
.divbox{
float:left;
width:100px;
}
```

This code does nearly what I needed but, not always. So, that not gonna work.

Comment: This is standard behaviour of flexbox layout, just create a wrapping flex row. Add `align-items: flex-start` (default is `stretch`)

Comment: Thanks!!! I'll look in to flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS flexbox. here's the link for more information https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/9kn8L4a2/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div{
            width:100px;
            background-color: blue;
            border:solid 2px black;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        body{
            width:100%;
            display:flex;
            align-items:flex-start;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
            <div style="height:200px"></div>
            <div style="height:300px"></div>
            <div style="height:100px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!